# flatten a dataframe into dictionary with key given by index and column names

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
             v1        v2        v3
c1
a      1.593979  1.679763  1.613202
n      1.327004  2.551197  1.492442
z      1.615528  1.156273  1.817987
```

I would like to create a dictionary from the dataframe.
I know I can do

```
d = {str(i): v for i,v in enumerate(var.values.flatten()))}
```

and create a dictionary with items `1.593979,1.679763 , ...` and keys '0','1','2', etc...

However, I would like the keys of my new dictionary to be a combination of the original columns and index names e.g.

```
dict_result={'v1_a':1.593979,'v2_a':1.679763,...,'v3_z':1.817987}
```

How to achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and flatten indices, last call [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
s = df.unstack()
s.index = s.index.map('_'.join)
#alternative
#s.index = ['{}_{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in s.index ]

d = s.to_dict()
print (d)
{'v2_n': 2.551197, 'v1_a': 1.593979, 'v1_n': 1.327004, 
'v2_a': 1.6797630000000001, 'v3_z': 1.8179869999999998, 
'v3_n': 1.492442, 'v1_z': 1.615528, 'v2_z': 1.1562729999999999, 'v3_a': 1.613202}
```

Comment: the answer is definitely correct and great. In the worst case I have a float index, how do I cast it to string so that join can be used?

Comment: I add alternative.